# C4996 System Cannot Find The File Specified

Tags: c++

```
#include "Time.h"

void Time::timerStart()
{
    tBegin = clock();
}

double Time::timerStop()
{
    tEnd = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(tEnd - tBegin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return elapsed_secs;
}

string Time::getDate(char delimiter)
{
    time_t t = time(0);   //now
    struct tm *now = localtime(&t);

    ostringstream ss; //use iss or oss and NOT ss (bulkier)
    ss << now->tm_mday << delimiter << (now->tm_mon + 1)
        << delimiter << (now->tm_year + 1900);

    return ss.str();
}

string Time::getTime(char delimiter)
{
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm *now = localtime(&t);

    ostringstream ss;
    ss << now->tm_hour << delimiter << now->tm_min << delimiter << now->tm_sec;

    return ss.str();
}
```

Basically I keep getting Error Code C4966 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable depreciation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

I used _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in the preprocessor definitions and it still gives me the same error. Im so lost on how to run this program and I've spent literally hours looking for solutions online and trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does "System Cannot Find The File Specified" have to do with using a potentially unsafe `localtime` ? Where *exactly* did you come across that error message text (the file text in your question title) ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to `Preprocessor` works for me, if not for you, try other solutions below:

**Solution 1:**
Define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the beginning of your file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <time.h>
```

**Solution 2:**

Add `4996` to :

```
YourProject->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Disable Specific Warnings
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The first solution worked. THANK YOU. I LOVE YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helps.